# How to get X and Y of current location of user using MapBox GeolocateControl

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl

How can I get the X and Y of GeolocateControl after it geolocated on the map?

I tried to this like

```
setTimeout(function(){  
 var userlocation = geolocate.Position;
 var lat = userlocation.latitude;
 var lng = userlocation.longitude;
  console.log(lat);
 }, 3000);
```

but it is not returning anything. and I am getting this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'coords' of undefined

Code:

```
let geolocate = new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
    positionOptions: {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        watchPosition: true
    }
});
map.addControl(geolocate);
map.on('load', function(){
    geolocate.trigger();
});

setTimeout(function(){  
 var userlocation = geolocate.Position;
 var lat = userlocation.coords.latitude;
 var lng = userlocation.coords.longitude;
  console.log(lat);
 }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

The Geolocate Control has a [`geolocate` event](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#geolocatecontrol.event:geolocate) which fires each time the [Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation) position update returns successfully. Assuming that `geolocate` is the variable containing your control instance, your code would look like this:

```
geolocate.on('geolocate', function (position) {
    const latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    const longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    console.log('lat, lng', latitude, longitude);
});
```